# How to install eiffel on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

How can I install the eiffel programming language? I run Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit) but I don't have a window manager, only ssh (as ec2 instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation of EiffelStudio on Linux Ubuntu is quite simple. Open a terminal and type the following command lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eiffelstudio-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install eiffelstudio
```

Check [this](https://launchpad.net/~eiffelstudio-team/+archive/ppa) for more information.